# Show/hide list ul from divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<ul>
 <div class="sub_cat_box"> 

 <li class="current"><a href="#">Cat 1</a></li> 
   <ul> 
     <li><a href="#">Prod1</a></li> 
     <li><a href="#">Prod1</a></li> 
   </ul> 

 </div> 

 <div class="sub_cat_box"> 

 <li class="current"><a href="#">Cat 2</a></li> 
   <ul> 
     <li><a href="#">Prod1</a></li> 
     <li><a href="#">Prod1</a></li> 
   </ul> 

  </div> 
</ul>
```

I want to show/hide each child `<ul>` when I click the `<li class='current'>`. I tried with jQuery, but I didn't make it.

Comment: -1 He didn't try at all, that's what I read from his question.

Comment: Your HTML fragment doesn't look valid; suggest you validate it and then include it in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Use jQuery to select li elements with the class selector, then bind an event handler to the click function. The bound function should find the next ul relevant to the selected element and call the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method upon it.  By default the jQuery toggle method will toggle the visibility of an element:

```
$(".current").click(function(){
  $(this).next("ul").toggle();
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ytXFQ/

Answer (score 5):

Your HTML is not correct.

Try it with this HTML structure:

```
<ul>
 <li class="current">
    <a href="javascript: toggleChildren('cat1');">Cat 1</a>
    <div class="sub_cat_box" id="cat1">
      <ul> 
        <li><a href="#">Prod1</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Prod1</a></li> 
      </ul> 
    </div>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Function:

```
function toggleChildren(id) {

   var elem = document.getElementById(id);
   if(!elem) alert("error: not found!");
   else {

      if(elem.style.display == "block")
         elem.style.display = "none";

      else
         elem.style.display = "block";
   }
}
```

CSS:

```
.sub_cat_box {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is not valid (only il is allowed inside ul, and div and other uls must be inside lis). It should be something like this:

```
<ul>

    <li class="current"><div class="sub_cat_box"> 
       <a href="#">Cat 1</a>
       <ul> 
         <li><a href="#">Prod1</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">Prod1</a></li> 
       </ul> 
       </div> 
      </li> 
     <li class="current">     
      <div class="sub_cat_box"> <a href="#">Cat 2</a> 
       <ul> 
         <li><a href="#">Prod1</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">Prod1</a></li> 
       </ul>         
      </div> 
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Once it is done like that, you can apply code like this:

```
$(".current").click(function(e){
     $(this).find('ul').toggle();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li.current').on('click', 'a', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: it is important to handle the click event on the anchor tag and not on the li because the anchor tag has already an associated event, which in your case, will append # to your url location and add an unnecessary history entry on your browser. Hence, the return false over there.

Comment: and your html is unvalid. you can't have ul's inside ul's, unless they are inside li's themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(document).on("click", "li.current > a", function(){
   $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.current').next('ul').hide();​​​ // Make them hide by default
  $('.current').click(function(){
     $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
  });
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yyy7u/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("ul > li.current").on('click', 'a', function(){
      $('ul.class').children().toggle();
    });
```

Where class is your ul class. This is the cleanest jQuery code, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li.current a').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().next('ul').slideToggle(); // or
  //$(this).parent().next('ul').toggle();
});
```